# Arena Simulation 6 different time zone for each time zone for each 6 different distribution for 1 Create module

Tags: arena-simulation

I want to use 6 different distributions for 6 different time zones for a single Create for my project. However, when I try to add the attribute, I get an error. I look forward to your help in this matter.

Demonstration of how to do it with attribute or another way on the arena simulation program.